# Unix - search a value and print before line

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have below input and output needed.

input :

```
insert xxx to table xx.xxx.
1
insert yyy to table yy.yyy
10000
```

output:

```
insert yyy to table yy.yyy
10000
```

I want to print the a line before the value >= 10000.

tried wasnt wrking:

```
awk '($1>10000) {print$1)' < log2 > log3 | awk '/[0-9]$/ {print $1)' < log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '/10000/{print line ORS $0} {line=$0}' file
insert yyy to table yy.yyy
10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it's stated in the question, you need to get the before line and the pattern ('10000' for your example) line right?

I think the easiest way to do it is using grep:

```
grep -B 1 '^([1-9]\d{4,})$' file
```

or if you want to print it to an output file:

```
grep -B 1 '^([1-9]\d{4,})$' file > outputFile
```

It gets values that start with 1 and have 4 or more digits after. ^ and $ to guarantee that the line only contains the numeric value in it (^ is the line beginning and $ is the line end).

This, for the input you suggested will output:

```
insert yyy to table yy.yyy
10000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
awk '{if (($1+0==$1) && $1 >= 10000) {print a; print}; a=$0}' < input
```

Here, `($1+0==$1)` makes sure that `$1` is a number, and `$1 >= 10000` check that it is not smaller than 10000. If both conditions are met, it prints the current and the last line, which was saved using `a=$0`.